# how to fix "The following classes needed for analysis were missing"

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

i try to start a sonarqube analyze in my java project, but the task stops with an error.

Here the facts:
gradle wrapper 4.10
sonarqube-gradle-plugin: 2.7.1
java 8

i have defined the plugin and execute "gradlew sonarqube". After that, all my unittest were executed ... but suddenly the process stopps with an error message :

**The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
  apply
  test
  accept**

```
18:20:37: Executing task 'sonarqube'...

:wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test NO-SOURCE
> Task :frontend:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :frontend:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :frontend:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :frontend:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :frontend:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :frontend:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :frontend:test NO-SOURCE
> Task :frontend:jar
> Task :application:compileJava
> Task :application:processResources
> Task :application:classes
> Task :application:compileTestJava
> Task :application:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :application:testClasses
> Task :application:test
The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
  apply
  test
  accept
> Task :sonarqube

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 25s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
18:21:03: Task execution finished 'sonarqube'.
```

if tried a downgrade of the sonarqube-plugin-version but it doesnt help.

How can i fix it?

best regards

Michael

Comment: Maybe releated to [this](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/issues/105) issue?

Answer (score 5):

These warnings seems to be a bug regarding Java 8 lamda support in `find-sec-bugs` project:

- https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/issues/123
- https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/issues/332

It seems that there is no fix for the bug, yet.

Comment: @BalajiRajendran https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/527#issuecomment-870072219

Answer (score 0):

These are coming from findbugs plugin, remove this plugin from your project and retry. This issue will not come.

And just a suggestion, you should trust on the dedicated SonarSource maven scanner plugin for your project, instead of standard sonar scanner, which is not optimal for maven project.

The maven plugin would configure your analysis, considering most of the complexity of your maven architecture.